# MagicalRecord import only saving last item

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, magicalrecord

I have an AFNetworking call that is calling my API and storing the results. I have a similar call that is working just fine this way. However for this one it seems to only be storing the last item.

```
[client getPath:@"GetItemsByFilter/" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Operation: %@", operation);
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

        NSArray *customerFieldResults = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"details.items"];
        NSLog(@"Results: %@", customerFieldResults);
        __block NSArray *array;
        @try {
            [CustomerFields MR_truncateAll];
            array = [CustomerFields MR_importFromArray:customerFieldResults];
            NSLog(@"done setting array: %@", array);


        } @catch (NSException *e) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        } @finally {
            NSLog(@"tc done");

        }
        NSLog(@"Array 1: %@", array);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kCustomerFieldSetComplete object:nil];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Operation: %@", operation);
        NSError *jsonError;
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[error localizedRecoverySuggestion] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]);

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Api Error: %@", [dict valueForKey:@"status"]] message:[dict valueForKey:@"statusMessage"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", @"Okay button") otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
    }];
```

When I do it with a context, it doesn't even save the items. I am sending a notification when the receiving of this information is complete and in that notification I am displaying the results from a `[CustomerFields findAll]`. Only one item is found with a `[CustomerFields findAll]`.

Array1 shows the complete list of items, but once I get back to the other controller it only returns the very last item that was in the array. Also if I wrap this in a `saveWithBlock` it will not see any items in the other controller.

Why is it only showing the last record from the import when I do a `findAll`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Magical Record, but perhaps you're not saving your core data context?

I assume that the method `MR_importFromArray:` inserts the records into CoreData?

If that's not the case, you perhaps want to loop through your results and create them one by one?

```
[client getPath:@"GetItemsByFilter/" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSArray *customerFieldResults = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"details.items"];

    customerFieldResults = [CustomerFields MR_importFromArray:customerFieldResults];

    //loop through array and create records

    //save your core data context here

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kCustomerFieldSetComplete object:nil];
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out the API I was using changed and the field I was using as the `relatedByAttribute` was coming back blank (a bug) so it was thinking all my records were duplicates and overwriting them.